# Visualize a SVM model having100 attributes in 2D plot python

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, svm, text-classification

I am using SVM for text classification (tf-idf score based classification).
Is it possible to plot SVM having more than 100 attributes and 10 labels. Is there any way to reduce the features and then plot the same multiclass SVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input data of higher dimensionality, I think that there is not a direct way to render a SVM. You should apply a dimensionality reduction, in order to have something to plot in 2-d or 3-d.